# failed to load resource 499 error

Tags: javascript, symfony, error-handling

User is not able to select T&C checkbox after scrolling down through agreement file. This issue is happening only on one system, which have kaspersky antivirus but it is turned off.

It is throwing following error in console:

```
failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 499 (request has been forbidden by antivirus) notifier.js

failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 499 () stats.g.doubleclick.....
```

Not sure what is causing this error and not enabling the checkbox.

Anyone have any idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your library loaded through a CDN? I think the user uses a kind of adblock in his browser

Comment: Yes, library is loaded through CDN but user confirmed that adblock is also disabled.

Comment: You could load the library through your local files to avoid that problem